# How to specify different application.conf for specs2 tests?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, specs2

I have an IntelliJ IDEA project in Scala and started adding org.specs2 tests. I am having trouble finding out how to put in an application.conf file that will be used by the tests.

I have tried doing the following:

```
test
    resources
        application.conf 
    scala
        mypackage.myname
            MyTestSpec
```

then called

```
ConfigFactory.load()
```

in MyTestSpec. Nothing was loaded, though, neither the application.conf from my resources subfolder of the src folder, nor this one. My goal is to be able to write integration tests against some test environments (please let's not debate the validity of this goal...).

How to go about doing this or is there a better way of going about it? I started reading the specs2 documentation today and I am pretty new to Scala as well so I am just assuming here that this is how test configurations are supposed to work.

So far I have attempted to specify -Dconfig.file=my_test_conf_full path in the build configuration for the tests (from the Build/Configurations... menu in IntelliJ), however that did not make any difference.

Thank you.

Comment: You can pass a string with the path to your resources file, and the 'ConfigFactory' will load the file from the file system, rather than using the class loader. You can also build your own configs using the `ConfigValueFactory`. I have used the former successfully for my testing, but the latter looks interesting, too.

Answer (score 10):

## Using SBT

Place your custom configuration file at `src/test/resources/application.test.conf`.

Then, add this to your `build.sbt`:

```
// When running tests, we use this configuration
javaOptions in Test += s"-Dconfig.file=${sourceDirectory.value}/test/resources/application.test.conf",
// We need to fork a JVM process when testing so the Java options above are applied
fork in Test := true,
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've created a configuration for a test in the the Run/Debug menu:

Assuming your test.conf file is in the main conf directory, you can use this "-Dconfig.resource=test.conf".

If you want to keep it in test/resources then it'd be "-Dconfig.resource=resources/test.conf".

In a JUnit config menu add the line to "VM options."

In a Specs2 config menu add the line to "VM parameters."

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a string with the path to your resources file, and the 'ConfigFactory' will load the file from the file system, rather than using the class loader. See [overview](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).

You can also build your own configs using the `ConfigValueFactory`. See [`ConfigValueFactory`](https://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigValueFactory.html).

I have used the former successfully for my testing, but the latter looks interesting, too.

Comment: Thank you; I have tried that, ConfigFactory.load("my test path"), however that did not work. The returned config object did not have my values in it.

Comment: You need to use `ConfigFactory.parse("/home/BobDalgleish/project1/proj/test/application.conf")` to tell it to parse a file path. `load()` just takes a file name that is loaded by the class loader.

Comment: I have used a method called parseFile, as parse does not exist. This was more along the lines of `val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("/home/cn/IdeaProjects/recommender-integration/src/test/resources/application.conf"))`. Weirdly enough that did not help either. I have checked and re-checked the file is at the specified location.

Comment: Here is some verbatim code I used, that works:   `val userPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"),
    "src", "test", "resources", "application.conf")
  ... val c = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new java.io.File(userPath.toString()))`. I prefer building up file paths using Java path expressions.

Comment: Thank you, that of course is way better, however it does not solve the issue of the file just not being found; hard-coding paths is almost always bad, I have done just to see if it can load files from the specified location but something is definitely messed up, as it does not work. Surely it just can't be difficult to load one file! so I'm guessing it's some very weird particular case happening here, specific to my machine and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the application.conf in IntelliJ via Project Settings:

File - Project structure - Modules - Sources - select Folder (e.g. src/ressources) -> Mark as: Click Resources

The ressources folder is added to the pane on the right. Now things like

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
val value = ConfigFactory.load().getString("my.secret.value") // or
val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
```

start working.